# How to get all faces based on a certain angle of their normals?

Tags: python, scripting, faces, normals, mathematics

I would like to create a list of faces/polygons based on the *angle* of each corresponding normal. I've tried something like `board.data.polygons[0].normal > 0`, but that doesn't seem to work.

[image]

**Question:** How to pick the normals that are pointing downwards `(-z axis)` and append their associated faces/polygons to a new list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use [`Vector.angle(Vector)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.angle)**

To get all normals that are within 89 degrees of the -z axis in local space (`down = Vector((0, 0, -1)`) use `face.normal.angle(down)` which calculates the angle between the face normal and the local vector pointing down.

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from mathutils import Vector
context = bpy.context
obj = context.object
me = obj.data
down = Vector((0, 0, -1)) #  -z axis.
test_angle = radians(89) 
# list all faces with normal less than 89 degrees to down
faces = [f for f in me.polygons 
        if f.normal.angle(down) < test_angle]

print(faces)
```

Change the `test_angle` value to suit.

Answer (score 1):

`board.data.polygons[0].normal`returns a vector(x,y,z). You need to choose the axis you want to compare in your case "Z". So:

```
board.data.polygons[0].normal[2] < 0:
    #do something here
```

Note if you only want the faces pointing directly down, you have to compare to -1.0(`board.data.polygons[0].normal[2] == 1.0`)

Comment: IMO never use equality (`x == 1.0`) with floats, always use a tolerance. `abs(x - 1.0) < TOL`