# Python/API - How do Normals work?

Tags: python, normals

I'm writing a program that snaps objects to random parts of a larger objects. Right now I've been looping through all the vertices of the main object, grabbing the coordinates of a random vertex and snapping the new object to that location. However, I would like loop through all the faces instead, and only snap to faces that face a certain direction. I'm testing out how this will work in the console with this code:

```
bpy.data.objects["BaseTerrain"].data.polygons[0].normal
```

Which is giving me this output:

```
Vector((-0.6524375677108765, -0.7578425407409668, -0.0))
```

What do those numbers mean? I know they're the x,y,z coordinates of something, but I'm not really sure how that relates to the normal. I'm sure it's something really obvious I'm missing, so hopefully someone can point it out!

Comment: They're the X, Y, and Z component of the normal vector. That is, if you placed the origin of the vector at the origin, they're the xyz coordinate of the vector's tip.

Comment: ... in Object Space..

Comment: That makes sense. I guess my math knowledge is lacking here. What determines the length of the vector?

Comment: The length is always 1.

Comment: Ah, did not know that, thanks! Then what would be the best way to find the direction of faces so I snap objects to faces that are facing up? Get the normal of a face and compare it with the vertices of that face and see if they're all the same z value (or close)?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. I'd say a poly is facing up if polygon.normal[2] > 0.9. Adjust 0.9 for more/less tolerance.

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Suggest searching for some primers on linear algebra (vectors & matrices). (or dust off some high school texts)  The face [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) is a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector).  If two unit vectors `v1` and `v2` point in the same direction then their dot product is 1 `v1.dot(v2) == 1`  and the angle between them is 0, `v1.angle(v2) == 0`   Use to test against any reference vector.    [Example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96066/how-to-get-all-faces-based-on-a-certain-angle-of-their-normals)